Vapi Custom LLM - PHP
I want to use the Vapi Custom LLM, but with PHP.
I have set everything up on my server, and when Vapi starts, the call initially connects. Then since the data is sent over to my server I process the response, but when I try to pass the response back, nothing happens, it does not speak the response. I see there is a Python script that can do this, but I don't want to run Python in the server environment that I built.
Is there a way to handle Vapi Custom LLMs with a PHP page?
I have tried changing the JSON output but that does not seem to work.
